# Is "efficient wattage" a correct term?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I'm an engineering student studying for the proofreading course I'm taking. In one of the practice sets there's a sentence that's been marked correct but the bold italicized words just don't make sense to me from the scientific standpoint. If I'm wrong, can someone explain it to me why? The set is about food processors.

"They provide warranties with their products, along with quality attachments, ***efficient wattages*** and various bowl sizes."

Comment: Is it specifically an engineering proofreading course (where one might be expected to follow the guidance in ISO 80000-1 with respect to naming physical quantities), or is it a non-discipline-specific proofreading course?

Comment: reads like sales mumbo sized jumbo to me.  warranties with products- fraud is illegal in most places so warranting that a product works as advertised should be implicit.  quality attachments- quality is vague as opposed to "durable" or "useful."  various bowl sizes- can mean "bowls of various sizes sold separately" or as options as opposed to "various sized bowls."  efficient wattage- at least means "uses less power compared to something else" even if it does not say what or under what conditions (peak vs rated (aka max) vs actual).

Comment: @DanielHatton Just a general proofreading course and the sets strike me as something written for ESL students. Since I'm an ETL myself and an engineering student to that, I just needed to understand this because it'd bug me.

Comment: @RainbowAngle  OK.  I asked because ISO 80000-1 strongly discourages the use of names for quantities such that the name is constructed from a particular unit of measurement ("wattage", "voltage", etc., although it grudgingly accepts "molar volume").  But if the course is not engineering-specific, that's probably irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

I think it makes about as much sense as "quality attachments". We can infer that they mean "attachments that are of high quality" but it's not very good English to use "quality" as an adjective.

Likewise, I think "efficient wattages" is supposed to mean "wattage ratings that show high power efficiency".

If I was proofreading that sentence I would look for **parallel construction** of the list items and a comma before "and".

Please, please, for the love of all that is holy, do not add the words "seamless" or "performant".

Comment: I agree with your answer. There's a difference between *wrong*, and *unclear*. So, this sentence being marked as "correct" doesn't mean it cannot be improved.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Thanks, that's what I thought too. This is one of those time where just because something is not technically incorrect, doesn't mean that it's actually correct.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though it's a translation error of sorts. Wattage is a measurement of power, often interchanged with (US) horsepower. Even efficient horsepower makes little sense. Efficient use of (power) does make sense, but out of context, it's difficult to determine if that's appropriate.

This might be a question better suited for a grammar SE?

Comment: the little sense of "efficient horsepower" is usually that there tend to be tradeoffs between power and efficiency for a given size.  It becomes a statement of retaining efficiency despite delivering high output power (input power close to output power).  While it could mean high efficiency for a wattage class, that's more applicable to microwave ovens than food processors.  some blender type devices take pride in being able to heat soup rather than the efficiency of their cutting/mixing.

Comment: @fred_dot_u I'm content that it may be grammatically correct but the "efficient wattage" was bothering me from an engineering standpoint.

Comment: @Abel Those were my exact thoughts! Also, the tea is hot :)